# Git: How to save a branch's history into a single file

Tags: git

I'm iterating on a code feature in a Git branch that will eventually be boiled down into a single commit/patch via rebase. However, I still want to keep the original commits around in a single history file somehow, so I have a record of my work. What is the best way to do this?

The best method I can think of right now would be to use `git format-patch master` and then concatenate together all of the patch files generated into a single file. The only problem with this approach is that I'm lazy. I can't be bothered to do all that outside of git.

Comment: why not simply creating a new branch (label) at the branches head?

Comment: My feature branch is completely local to my machine. It will never get pushed to origin except via my one-commit patch. So I want to save that branch history to my personal records via a single patch file. Does that clarify?

Comment: Another thing is that my local repo is not a dedicated fork or anything like that; it's simply a throw-away clone of the origin. So I want to save off my branch history and then not care about what happens to the local git repo.

Comment: You have this thee options: **1)** push the feature branch (copy) before squashing **2)** change your workflow and keep the local repo instead of trowing it away **3)** create an additional remote where you push your branch before squashing.

Comment: If you want to keep it "just in case", and dont suspect you will need it, you can simply zip the `.git` folder and save it. Not saying you should tho - I'd simply keep the changes in an addition remote repo.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Good options. I'm trying out a unique workflow where I save off all my patches into a git repo dedicated to storing patch text files. This is nice because I don't have to deal with the thousands of commits and the huge size of the project I forked or do git magic to see my patches, since they are all sitting as text files.

Comment: @Andersnk Good idea, though now there is an additional hoop to jump through to view the branch commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches in git are cheap. Branch is just a file showing a commit in your repository (I'm deliberately skipping potential GC when you'll squash, merge and delete branch).

The "git-way" of doing that would be just to:

```
git branch feature-backup
git rebase <some_commit>
```

After that `feature-backup` branch will still have your old history. You don't need to push `feature-backup` branch to remote. It could be just your local branch.

The other approach to have the changes from your branch would be:

```
git diff <some_commit>...HEAD > all_commits_in_a_single_file.patch
git rebase <some_commit>
```

With that you'll have all the changes that are on your branch in a single patch file.

If you'd like to have all the commits separated you could use:

```
git log --cc <some_commit>...HEAD > all_history_in_a_single_file.txt
```

The last option would give you all concatenated diffs with commit messages and stuff.

Comment: These are great ideas, but don't quite fit what I'm looking for. 1) requires me to keep a git repo around. I want to save off a single file and potentially delete the old local repo. 2) doesn't work for me because it throws away all the commit messages and commit dates. I want to keep those around so I can see when I worked on what. The icing on the cake for the solution I'm looking for would be if I could 'apply' this file to give me my branch back if I clone a new repo.

Comment: If I did want to use solution 1) with a remote fork, I guess I could just push a tag pointing to the tip of my branch once I'm finished with the patch, right? Is this the workflow most common with people keeping track of their work on patches for other projects?

Comment: I'm using tags sparingly, but yes such tag would be similar branch that you'd push - in both cases your commits will be reachable by anyone who clones remote repository. 

Please take a look at the third option posted above, I think that this one is the one that fulfill all your needs.

Comment: Beautiful! I think the last solution is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Is there a way to "apply" that single file back into a git repo? That's not required for me, but it would be nice

Comment: AFAIK no. That's a drawback of that, but that's exactly what you've asked for. You could go with a mix of 2nd and 3rd approach. Output form 2nd would be used with `git apply`, 3rd will give you full history.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this:

```
git format-patch --stdout <commit_or_branch> > <patchfile>
```

This concatenates all the commits after `<commit_or_branch>` into a single output, and `>` redirects that output from stdout into a patch file of the name `<patchfile>`. This patch file can now be easily applied via `git am <patchfile>`.

We use this method to transact in multi-commit patch files at my company, and it works very nicely.

---

How is the solution above different than this solution mentioned by Marcin Pietraszek?

```
git log --cc <some_commit>...HEAD > all_history_in_a_single_file.txt
```

The difference is that Marcin's solution does not produce a "patch" file that can be consumed by `git am`.

Here's an example to show how they are different for the same two commits. My method:

```
$ git format-patch --stdout origin/master 
From 33b83d0314c9c3090a0e27e4c2b46beb58ee1739 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: REDACTED
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:21:13 -0600
Subject: [PATCH 1/2] Test 1

---
 INSTALL | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/INSTALL b/INSTALL
index fb926ff73b..ae3c3e312d 100644
--- a/INSTALL
+++ b/INSTALL
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Copyright 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 Free Software
 Foundation, Inc.
-
+Hi
    This file is free documentation; the Free Software Foundation gives
 unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
 
-- 
2.25.1


From 88ff375059e12d6053ab43cfdeeefd179e24a2db Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: REDACTED
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:21:37 -0600
Subject: [PATCH 2/2] test 2

---
 INSTALL | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/INSTALL b/INSTALL
index ae3c3e312d..97d6a8f86a 100644
--- a/INSTALL
+++ b/INSTALL
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Copyright 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 Free Software
 Foundation, Inc.
-Hi
+Hello
    This file is free documentation; the Free Software Foundation gives
 unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
 
-- 
2.25.1
```

Marcin's method:

```
$ git log --cc origin/master...HEAD 
commit 88ff375059e12d6053ab43cfdeeefd179e24a2db (HEAD -> temp)
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 14 18:21:37 2021 -0600

    test 2

diff --git a/INSTALL b/INSTALL
index ae3c3e312d..97d6a8f86a 100644
--- a/INSTALL
+++ b/INSTALL
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Copyright 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 Free Software
 Foundation, Inc.
-Hi
+Hello
    This file is free documentation; the Free Software Foundation gives
 unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
 

commit 33b83d0314c9c3090a0e27e4c2b46beb58ee1739
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Wed Apr 14 18:21:13 2021 -0600

    Test 1

diff --git a/INSTALL b/INSTALL
index fb926ff73b..ae3c3e312d 100644
--- a/INSTALL
+++ b/INSTALL
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Copyright 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 Free Software
 Foundation, Inc.
-
+Hi
    This file is free documentation; the Free Software Foundation gives
 unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.
```